# How to display the div right inside of the container if parent div is fixed and child div is absolute?

Tags: html, css

I am using bootstrap `container`. I have a parent div with `position: fixed` and child div with `position: absolute`. I set both positions `right:0` so that my div will display the right side.

Now the issue is, I am using bootstrap container. It is displaying totally right side of the sidebar. I mean it crosses the container limit. I can set the right value but I don't think this is a good idea.

**Note:** There is no border in the container. I created in the paint to explain my issue. Check out the snippet on full screen. The circle is showing near the scroll bar. I need inside the container.

Is there any other way to do this?

Getting output.

You can check my div is cross the limit of the container.

[image]

I need output

[image]

```css
.google-container {
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

.google_1 {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  background-color: #EFBD40;
}

.google-container .google_1 h2 {
  margin: auto;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 28px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <div class="google-container">
    <div class="google_1">
      <h2>google</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You do realize that your code doesn't show or produce the problem you're facing.

Comment: in your code no container div border display which you explain in question ...?

Comment: Can't see the problem in the snippet

Comment: @Bhargav, There is no border, That border is the container width, I created in the paint to explain my issue.

Comment: I think it's because your google-container is missing width and height. The browser won't autosize a container which has child content either floating around or positioned absolutely.
Look at the fiddle here (https://jsfiddle.net/pxmpkcp7/) and notice that if you remove width and height, then a black dot is shown near the top right of the 'container'. That's your google-container.

Comment: @Bhuwan, No that not solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.google_1').css({
  'right': $('.container').offset().left
});
```

This will always align the `google_1` box to right of the `container` width

> Note: *Try the below snippet in full screen mode (Expand Snippet)*

```js
$('.google_1').css({
  'right': $('.container').offset().left
});
```

```css
.google-container {
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

.google_1 {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  background-color: #EFBD40;
}

.google-container .google_1 h2 {
  margin: auto;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 28px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <div class="google-container">
    <div class="google_1">
      <h2>google</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can we do without Jquery?

Comment: @NarendraVerma without jQuery it will not be possible for all devices as width will not be same for all. You can give a fixed value for a particular device in css but in jQuery this will work for all type of devices.